# MVC 5 posting with Ajax and returning PartialView calls GET after POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm still learning how to use Partial Views with Ajax but I'm not understanding why my scenario is calling the GET after the POST. This is effectively causing a page refresh and defeating the whole purpose of the Ajax update.

I have a Razor page that uses a partial view to write out records in a table format. At the bottom of the page there is a textbox that allows for the user to submit a new comment and the idea is to insert that comment into the database and then have just the table updated.

This the majority of my .cshtml page. Some labels and textboxes have been removed for brevity.

```
<form id="logForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div id="exceptionTable">
        @Html.Partial("_DailyLogExceptionsTable", Model)
    </div>

    <div class="well">
        <div class="row voffset3">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                Enter Exception Log comment
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ExceptionComment, new { cols = 200, @rows = 4, @maxlength = "100", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "100 character limitation" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ExceptionComment, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row voffset3">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
                </button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="@Url.Action("ScheduleDetails", "Home")" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cancel
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="150" />
    </div>

</form>
```

This is my partial view that just contains a table (_DailyLogExceptionsTable).

```
if (Model.listExceptions.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="row voffset3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <table class="table">
                @foreach (var item in Model.listExceptions)
                {
                    //write out rows
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is my jQuery function.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

    $("#loaderDiv").show();

    var data = $("#logForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Exception/DailyLog",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#loaderDiv").hide();

            $("#exceptionTable").html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 500) {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error.');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    })

});
```

This is my POST in the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DailyLog(ExceptionLogDailyViewModel vm)
{
    try
    {
        DAL.CommentInsertBySupervisor(vm, UserId);

        //repopulate the exceptions/comments.
        vm.listExceptions = DAL.GetEmployeeExceptionsByDate(vm.CurrentEmployeeId, vm.ShiftDate);        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log error
    }   

    return PartialView("_DailyLogExceptionsTable", vm);
}
```

When I debug I can see it call the POST and repopulate the partial view as it should and then right after the POST is finished it goes to the GET which creates a new ViewModel and uses a return View(vm) and effectively does a server side post. This causes the page to flash and moves the scrolls the page to the top.

Comment: Have you tried adding `return false;` and `e.preventDefault();` at the end of your click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit button is inside the `form` tag. clicking on the submit will fire a normal form submit. When doing ajax, you need to prevent this default behavior. Currently you are not doing this, hence it is making a normal form submit as well.

You can use the jQuery [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to do so

```
$(function(){

   $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       // your existing ajax code
   });

});
```

Instead of wiring up the submit button click event, you may consider wiring up the ajax code as an event handler for the `submit` event.

```
$(function(){

   $("#logForm").submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var data = $(this).serialize();
       var url = $(this).attr("action");
       // your existing ajax code
   });

});
```

Now this code will work for button click and form submit using enter key press

Another option is doing a `return false` from your callback method (which you wire up to the submit event/click event)

Comment: Perfect! I was following an article and he didn't have the e.preventDefault(). I switched over to using the #logForm.submit way like you showed. I do have a question with the URL portion though. You have the url set to the form's action which I'm assuming would set that to POST but what about telling it the /Controller/ActionResult to go to. Do I need to put that in the form somewhere if I want to use the url like you have? Right now I left the url the way I had it in the Ajax call and it works but that might not be the best way to do it.

Comment: form's action attribute value will have the url to which the form is being submitted. You can explicitly set it (`<form action="\Exception\DailyLog"></form>`). This way, you are reading from the UI. So if you ever want to change the form to be submitted to a different action method, you only update the HTML markup

Comment: Great! This is all coming together for me. I added the action in the form which I think makes it more readable anyway and then just set the url variable to ajax.url: url and it worked as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative path to the action method. Ex : `<form action='@Url.Aciton("DailyLog","Exception")'></form>`)